# Как изменить background-size на всех DIV на странице

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Необходимо с помощью jQuery установить аттрибут background-size на всех DIV на странице. Пробовал вот такую строку, но она не работает

```
$('div').css({'background-size': '0 0'});
```

Comment: почему решили, что не работает?

Comment: пробовал вставлять в код

Comment: На странице есть специальная кнопка Включения/Отключения изображений. Она должна работать не только при загрузке страницы

Comment: так почему вы решили что стили не применились? вы смотрели разметку после вызова данной функции? ваш html статичный или добавляется динамически?

Comment: @ArtB код сам по себе полностью рабочий. возможно вы его просто не вызываете? приведите весь пример, который вызывает у вас сомнения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#knopka').click(function(){
  $('div').css({'background-size': '0 0'});
 });
});
```

где **knopka** - айди вашей кнопки

Comment: [_For example, jQuery understands and returns the correct value for both .css({ "background-color": "#ffe", "border-left": "5px solid #ccc" }) and .css({backgroundColor: "#ffe", borderLeft: "5px solid #ccc" })_](http://api.jquery.com/css/)